# Как передать функцию в псевдомассив и вытащить значение из текущего элемента

Tags: javascript

У меня есть одинаковые элементы, и мне нужно добавить к текущему элементу с классом '.adventure-item' функцию offsetX и offsetY. Хочу сделать движение элемента за мышкой. Прикрепляю код и ссылку на codpen.

```
let add = document.querySelectorAll('.advantage-description'),
mainItem = document.querySelectorAll('.advantage-item'),
x,
y,
contain;

function go() {

function offsetY(el) {
let rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
return rect.top + scrollTop;;
}

function offsetX(sm){
let rects = sm.getBoundingClientRect();
return rects.left + scrollLeft;
}



mainItem.forEach(element => {
element.addEventListener('mousemove', second);
element.addEventListener('mouseout', four)
});




function second(event){
mainItem.forEach((element,i) => {
element.setAttribute('data' ,`sub-${i}`);
contain = this.getAttribute('data');
third(contain);
x = event.clientX;
y = event.clientY;
});
}


function third(contain) {
add.forEach((element,i) => {
element.classList.add(`sub-${i}`);
if(element.classList.contains(contain)){
element.style.display = 'block';
element.style.bottom = y + 'px';
element.style.right = x  + 'px';
}else{
element.style.display = 'none';
}

});
}
function four(e) {
add.forEach(element => {
element.style.display ='none'
});
}

}
go();
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/lore1ei/pen/RwNOvWR?editors=1010)

Comment: Проблема при прокрутке, если нажать f12 прокрутить ниже и навести курсор то текст уйдет выше.

Comment: Вопрос уточните, что вам нужно? Нормальный пример движения элемента за мышкой или подсказать, как передать функцию в псевдомассив?

Comment: Разобрался, но хотелось бы увидеть более адекватные способы связывать элементы. Просто мой код выглядит слишком загромажденным.